# "Please orange juice" is natural?

Tags: usage

When a server at a restaurant asks me "Anything to drink", I say "orange juice please." In that situation, can I say "Please orange juice"?

Comment: "I would like some orange juice, please" or "May I have some orange juice, please" is probably the most formal version one might use, but a simple "Orange juice, please" is certainly adequate in response to the query from the waitress. It is not generally idiomatic to place the "please" at the head of the statement for something like this (though when used in a way which interrupts another person, such as "Please, can you tell me how to get to Carnegie Hall?", the "please" often comes first, serving as an "interrupt" signal).

Answer (score 5):

I don't think that I have ever heard anyone respond with that particular word order. I do think it is correct though, if you speak with a pause after "please" (or place a comma there, if writing).

Saying "Please, orange juice" might be confusing and cause the server to ask you to repeat your response. I think using the response would be particularly troublesome in a restaurant that is fast-paced like many American restaurants.

Servers in most restaurants are probably used to hearing "*yes, [drink] please*" or "*[drink] please*" many times a day and hearing someone respond with something *almost* what they're expecting will probably make them think they misheard you, or that they simply didn't understand you. This could lead to you repeating yourself, or rewording your response *and* repeating yourself.
Either way, it *isn't* natural to make a simple response require a few sentences instead of a few words.

In conclusion, "Please orange juice" *could* be correct with a pause or comma after the word "Please". I don't think it would ever be *natural* in normal conversation. Ordering at a fine dining restaurant might be one example where the setting is formal enough for this phrase would seem more natural and perhaps not cause confusion. I would say in general, this wording is not natural.

Answer (score 3):

If the (brand) name of the orange juice you want is *Please* then you can say that; otherwise no, not really, not even with a comma: *Please, orange juice.*

The *please* at the beginning of the sentence sounds like an objection to something that the server has said.

Maybe he or she's asked if you if you want coffee, and you say

*Please! orange juice.*

accompanied by some hand waving and facial grimacing to indicate 'no' to coffee.

It is short for *Please, [no coffee, but I'll have] orange juice [instead].*

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I very rarely hear anyone ever use that phrase, but it is correct.  I would think that if you did use those words in that context you would say,"please, orange juice," as in "yes I would like a drink please" and then stating the preferred drink of choice.  So it makes much more sense if you add the comma but it also sounds very formal.  It's up to you.

Comment: The comma is important.

Comment: Yes, the comma is paramount in order to make that phrase correct.  I believe I said "it makes little sense" when I meant that it makes more sense.  Excuse my error.

Comment: @Abbey Since answers on Stack Exchange are intended to be retained for future reference, please edit your answer if you have made a mistake.